# Отправка формы после подтверждения reCaptcha

Tags: recaptcha, html, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы сразу после того как пользователь нажимает "я не робот", в reCaptcha от google сделать submit для формы?

Например, есть форма:

```
<form action="url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="sendLetter" name="sendLetter" target="_self">
  <input ...>1
  <input ...>2
  <input ...>3

<!-- та самая капча -->
<div class="g-recaptcha " data-sitekey="-key-" data-callback="go_submit"></div>

</form>
```

js:

```
    function go_submit() {

        var Forma = document.getElementById("sendLetter");
        Forma.submit(); //почему-то не срабатывает 
    }
```

Что тут не так, подскажите, пожалуйста? Вот скрин ошибки:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sup>Вынесенный ответ из тела вопроса</sup>*

Проблема была в том, что `input` `submit` имел `name` тоже `submit`, и js не понимал, что от него хотят.